# Network logons rejected only if they come from a specific machine

Tags: windows-7, windows, login

I have a problem that started happening a few days ago and I would appreciate any insights on why it is happening or at least how to diagnose it.

In this particular situation, there is machine Desktop which is running Windows 7 Pro and machine Server which is running SBS 2008.

For the past few days, Server started rejecting all network logins from Desktop.  For example, it will not map network shares, and attempts to use Remote Desktop also fail.

**This is not a "wrong password" or "user has no permissions" issue**, since the same user/password combination works perfectly when used from another machine.

When this first happened I used System Restore to go back in time before that night's security updates, and I was able to log in again from Desktop.  I blacklisted the updates so they won't get installed again, but this morning I have this issue again, and System Restore shows that all restore points are gone.

I have checked the Event Viewer on both Desktop and Server and there seems to be nothing related.  Does anybody have any idea of how to diagnose this?

Comment: Are you able to login locally with a local account with administrator rights? If that's possible, I would advice un-joining the machine and re-joining the machine to the domain.

Comment: Yes, I can log in locally.  Also, the machine is not on the domain.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question:

After a lot of searching in the event viewer and on the net, this turned out to be a corrupt certificate cache on the server machine.

This [great article](http://davidcmoisan.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/resolving-%E2%80%9Cpautoenr-dll-raised-an-exception%E2%80%9D/#comment-664) by David Moisan explains how to regenerate the certificate cache.

I recommend [applying the registry patch](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2379016) from KB2379016 **before** you follow David's instructions, as you may get hit by the bug described in the KB while following those instructions.